# React SPA path protection with standalone login page & API check

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a single-page React application with a very basic setup (compressed here):

```
function App() {
  const [ userLogin, setUserLogin ] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const result = AuthService.getAuthenticatedUser();
      setUserLogin(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching login data: ', error);
    }
  }, []);

  function RequireAuthentication({ redirectTo }) {
    return userLogin ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
  }

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={ <LoginPage /> } />
          <Route path="/logout" element={ <LogoutPage /> } />
          <Route path="/" element={ <RequireAuthentication redirectTo="/login" /> }>
            <Route path="/" element={ <div>lol</div> } />
            <Route path="option1" element={ <div>option1</div> } />
            <Route path="option2" element={ <div>option2</div> } />
            <Route path="option3" element={ <div>option</div> } />
          </Route>
          <Route path="*" element={ <Navigate to="/" /> } />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}
```

Right now my `AuthService` just looks at local storage and I will expand that to something that makes a REST API call to verify the persisted token is actually valid (and that the API is generally available).

I have two questions here, one of which I have a workaround answer to:

1. What is the idiomatic way to add a header/navbar that is hidden on the login page? (workaround below, and this is just for bonus points)
2. **The primary question:** My implementation currently resides in `useEffect`, which throws off the `RequireAuthentication` function. How do I force that to be evaluated and run the redirect only after the `useEffect` function completed?

I tried to put the call to `AuthService.getAuthenticatedUser` in the `RequiredAuthentication` function, but I am having problems making inline calls to Rest APIs and the solution I was pointed to was to use `useEffect` with `async` and `await`.

For my workaround on hiding a header, my workaround is something like this, where I render it as a parent above the `BrowserRouter` element:

```
return (
   <div className={ useLoggedIn ? 'hidden' : undefined }>This is my nav bar.</div>
);
```

Other things I looked at:

- I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513276/reactjs-with-react-router-single-page-application-spa-with-separate-login-page); however, it is 4 years old and I am sure React has updated
- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009071/how-can-i-protect-routes-in-my-reactjs-project) only has a single child element.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790081/login-page-separated-from-single-page-application-spa-in-reactjs) is also 4 years old
- etc.

Comment: The current version is react 18

Comment: @Evert I will update the tagline. I must be mixing up the router version vs. actual React.